# find the max value of each column of a 2d array

Tags: c, arrays

#i want to find the max value of each row, i already created an array in the main of size[5][2], and i want to find the max value for each column#

```
void
maximum(int a[5][2])
{

    int max = a[0][0];
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int max = a[0][i];

        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            if (a[j][i] > max)
                max = a[j][i];
    }
    printf("Maximum of 1st column= %d \n", max);

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int max = a[1][i];

        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            if (a[j][i] > max)
                max = a[j][i];
    }
    printf("Maximum of 2st column= %d \n", max);

    max = a[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] > max)
                max = a[i][j];
        }

    }
    printf("Maximum of all %d \n", max);
}
```

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i dont get you

Comment: @RAMA he means your code format is so bad.

Comment: @Hitokiri oh, i copied an pasted it from the compiler i work on:)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel okay sure

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Already reindented [by me]

Comment: You have a _function_ scoped: `int max = a[0][0];` You also have nested scoped declarations that _shadow_ that. Inside the `for` loops change the declarations into assignments (e.g.) `int max = a[0][i];` into `max = a[0][i];` And, for the top two, you probably need to move the `printf` to the bottom of the outer loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it the opposite way. `[0][i]` is the first row, not the first column. You must do it like `[i][0]` and `[i][1]`, and same for the j. It's `max=a[i][j]`.

Doing like like you say only checks the max of the first and second row, leaving the other three unchecked. Hope it helps.

Comment: i just tried it, it didn’t solve the problem, it prints the same value for both columns @AndreasWenzel

Comment: Could you upload the code like you have it just now?

Comment: can we contact by email its much easier from here @S_Rollan ?

Comment: @RAMA: Editing someone else's answer was not appropriate for this. It would be more appropriate to edit your question by adding the code (best without overwriting your original code). That way, everyone will be able to see the problem that you are now having.

Comment: sure dont worry, should not take much time at all :)

Comment: i did @S_Rollan

Comment: @RAMA: I have now rejected your edit and edited your question with your latest code. In future, feel free to edit your question yourself, but please don't delete your original question, because that would invalidate the answer.

Comment: I just did it, thanks much for the advise! @AndreasWenzel

Comment: @RAMA: Since you have now accepted this answer without further comment, I assume that your problem is solved and that the edit that I did to your question in which I posted your current code is now redundant. Therefore, I am reverting my edit to keep the question clean. If you still need it, feel free to edit your question again and/or revert my changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose carefully the indeces and their order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void show_max(int rows, int cols, int mat[rows][cols])
{ //              ^^^^      ^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    VLA notation

    // Traverse the array row-major order
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
    {
        int max = mat[r][0];
        //            ^^^^              First element of row r
        for (int c = 1; c < cols; ++c)
        {
            if (mat[r][c] > max)
                max = mat[r][c];
                //        ^^^^
        }
        printf("Max of ROW %d: %d\n", r, max);
    }

    int max_global = mat[0][0];

    // Traverse the array in colmun-major order
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c)              // <-- 
    {
        int max = mat[0][c];
        //            ^^^^                      // First element of column c
        for (int r = 1; r < rows; ++r)          // <-- 
        {
            if (mat[r][c] > max)
                max = mat[r][c];
                //        ^^^^          
        }
        printf("Max of COLUMN %d: %d\n", c, max);

        // This could be in the first nested loop.
        if (max > max_global)          
            max_global = max;
    }
    printf("Max ELEMENT: %d\n", max_global);
}


int main(void)
{
    int mat[5][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}};

    show_max(5, 2, mat);
}
```